# "this" on Javascript object methods

Tags: javascript

I am confused about javascript object methods on This and the implementation of ()=> instead of function(){},

Would you care to explain the behaviour of this: thanks

```js
const obj = {

    prop : 123,

    test : function (){
        console.log(this.prop);
    },

    test2 : ()=>{
        console.log(this.prop);
    },
}

console.log(test()); //results to 123
console.log(test2()); //results to undefined
```

Comment: Arrow functions automatically bind the `this` from the parent scope into the new function scope.

Comment: The `this` keyword in JavaScript does not behave like it does in C++, Java or C# - and sometimes it can behave unpredictably for beginners (e.g. in event-listeners).

Comment: I assume you mean `obj.test()` and `obj.test2()` in your example?  `test` and `test2` are not define globally so this gives errors.

Answer (score 3):

'this' keyword refers to the object context, when you call obj.test() that logs the property of that object (obj.prop). With the new method syntax introduced in ES6 we can omit the colon and the function keyword.

```js
const obj = {
    prop : 123,
    test(){
        console.log(this.prop);
    },
    test2: () => {
        console.log(this.prop);
    }
}

obj.test();   //123
obj.test2();  //undefined
```

If we use the 'this' keyword in a method then the value of 'this' is the calling object. Arrow functions inherently bind, an already defined 'this' value to the function itself that is NOT the calling object. In the code snippet above, the value of 'this' is the global object, or an object that exists in the global scope, which doesn’t have a 'prop' property and therefore returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks mate, where is the arrow function ()=> should be used to?

Comment: i modify the answer and explain what happen if we use arrow functions for methods

Comment: very clear and consise point @sonEtLumiere thanks,, would you say arrow functions can be used to shorten some codes that only.calls to global context properties?

Answer (score 1):

According to [You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond. Chapter 2. Syntax](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md) arrow functions are not only for shorter syntax for function declaration. It's about changing **THIS** behaviour.

In arrow function **THIS** is not dynamic, it's lexical.It points to surrounding scope, which is global so this.prop is undefined.

Example of correct using arrow function:

```
var controller = {
    makeRequest: function(..){
        btn.addEventListener( "click", () => {
            // ..
            this.makeRequest(..);
        }, false );
    }
};
```

We used arrow function for callback. So we can pass **THIS** from surrounding scope.

If we try to use regular function we have to pass **THIS** using `var`:

```
var controller = {
    makeRequest: function(..){
        var self = this;

        btn.addEventListener( "click", function(){
            // ..
            self.makeRequest(..);
        }, false );
    }
};
```