# Arrow Function returns undefined when called from an object but returns a string when called from a class instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

**1. I am calling a function `myDes()` which is an Arrow Function inside
an Object `Cameras`. It is returning `undefined`.**

**2. But when I call the function `myDes()` from a Class instance `obj1`
it returns a string - `"abc"`.**

> In my understanding arrow function binds by default the properties of
> the parent function or the global scope, then why does it not return
> the ***price*** in the first example as it does ***name*** in the
> second?

###### Example 1 — Calling from an Object

```js
const cameras = {
  price: 600,
  weight: 2000,
  myDes: () => {
    return `This canon camera is of ${this.price}`
  }
}

console.log(cameras.myDes()) // price undefined
```

###### Example 2 — Calling from an Instance of a Class

```js
class Student {
  name = 'abc'
  myDes = () => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}

let obj = new Student
obj.myDes() // return abc
```

*

> To the Comments Below suggesting some link reference for answers. What
> I meant since there is no parent function around the arrow function in
> the Class then how the arrow function is inheriting the properties of
> the class. To which a satisfied answer has been provided

- 

Comment: Arrow funcs don't respect `this`.

Comment: Arrow functions strongly bind at closure creation time. Normal `function`s do not.

Comment: You can check the scope by using `return this`. In the former example, you will see that `window` is returned. And window has no price.

Comment: btw, in the second example you don't need `myDes = () => {}`, you can use `myDes() {}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["this" on Javascript object methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63096148/this-on-javascript-object-methods)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions)

Comment: I am studing the link references given above. Will get back to you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, there is no parent function around the arrow function definition, so it does indeed bind to the global `this`. [An arrow function is not a method of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions).

In your second example, you are using [class field syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57608525/1048572). This is actually syntactic sugar for

```
class Student {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'abc'
    this.myDes = () => {
      console.log(this.name)
    }
  }
}
```

where the parent function is the constructor of the class, whose `this` value refers to the instance. This is also the value that the `this` inside the arrow function will refer to.

Answer (score -4):

As the comments to your question state, `this` inside arrow functions do not behave like you think. You may do this instead:

```js
const cameras = {
  price:600,
  weight: 2000,
  myDes: function(){
    return `This canon camera is of ${this.price}`
  }
}

console.log(cameras.myDes())
```

Comment: I am not the Downvoter but you were asking why the downvote on your now deleted answer. The asker seems to understand the nuance of an arrow function and is asking a different, very much interesting, question. Your answer does not address that while the comments actually explain this behavior. The asker did not ask how to make it "work" and infact has an working implementation of that. He inquired why it is different.